# Create a ScrollPanel - then place the results in there

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The code : The user enters a value and the code returns the computed value in a frame with a scrollbar because the frame is too small to contain the 100 lines.

```
package Gui;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Rekenen2 extends JFrame {

    public Rekenen2() {

        // setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JButton jbtComputeButton = new JButton("Compute");

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        final JTextField jtxInputTextField = new JTextField(8);

        final JLabel outputInPanel = new JLabel();

        panel1.add(jbtComputeButton, FlowLayout.LEFT);
        panel2.add(jtxInputTextField, FlowLayout.LEFT);
        panel3.add(outputInPanel);

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtComputeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int total = 0;

                int parsedInputValue = Integer.parseInt(jtxInputTextField
                        .getText());

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    total = (parsedInputValue * i);
                    outputInPanel.setText("" + total);

                }

            }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new Rekenen2();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.setTitle("Compute App");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: My code is almost ok but i'm really stuck here and i need your help.cheers

Comment: there really is not a question here - maybe consider edit.  You should create a ScrollPanel - then place your results in there. also, consider another type of control other than JLabel for large text strings.

Comment: I think a `JList` would be more appropriate here rather than a `JLabel`...

Comment: Hi, i whish i could give more precision in my question but the site is not accepting my edit so...

Comment: I'll try with a JList. Thank you

Comment: *" the site is not accepting my edit"*  I'm astonished.  What *exact* message is it giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the content in JScrollPane(then add the JScrollPane To JFrame). that will do the trick.